# Each item in Array is undefined...even though it's not (Node.js - sandboxed script)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Seeing strange behaviour in Node.js while mapping an array of strings. In the code below, the first map function properly prints the string in the `images` array. A line directly below, the `imgName` variable is `undefined` for each item in the loop.

```
images.map(function(imgName){console.log(imgName)}) // this properly prints each string in the array
images.map(function(imgName) { // each imgName returns undefined
  // first check the size of the image and instantiate canvas
  var dimensions = sizeOf(imgpath+imgName);
  if(debug) { console.log("Image dimensions "+imgpath+imgName+": "+dimensions.width+","+dimensions.height); }

  var canvas = new Canvas(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var Image = Canvas.Image;

  global.canvas = canvas;
  global.ctx = ctx;
  global.Image = Image;


  var img = new Image;
  img.src = fs.readFileSync(imgpath+imgName);
  tracking.track(img, tracker);
});
```

The only thing that makes me think something is interfering with the map is that the `tracking` variable at the bottom of the callback is sandboxed. Here's how I instantiate it:

```
var sandbox = function (files, sandbox) { 
  var source, script, result; 
  if (!(files instanceof Array)) { 
    files = [files]; 
  } 
    source = files.map(function (file) { 
    return fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'); 
  }).join(''); 
  if (!sandbox) { sandbox = {}; } 
  script = new Script(source); 
  result = script.runInNewContext(sandbox); 
  return sandbox; 
};

// instantiate sandboxed tracking class
var tracking = sandbox('./node_modules/tracking/build/tracking.js',{ navigator: {}, tracking: {}, window: {} }).tracking;
```

Is it possible this "sandbox" is interfering with the variables in scope in the loop (this sandbox is instantiated before the loop)? Or is there another cause?

### Update

I realized that if I removed all of the code and started adding each line in the loop one-by-one, the `imgName` variable is, in fact, defined. It appears that for whatever reason when an error is thrown inside the callback function, it then becomes undefined. Which is difficult because it seems to obscure the actual error and hinder debugging. Here's the error in the console:

```
fs.js:500
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/.../images/undefined'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
    at syncFileToBuffer (/Users/.../index.js:58:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../index.js:100:18)
    at /Users/.../extractor.js:59:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../extractor.js:57:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

Comment: I really don't think the tracking should interfere, but you shouldn't be using `map` to iterate over the array's elements, try using `forEach` instead

Comment: How strange, I wonder what's happening here. Thanks for pointing out the `forEach`, good call! Unfortunately it didn't fix it though ;)

Comment: I really can't see anything that might interfere, but I can try helping you out to debug (since I don't have the rest of your code). Try commenting some lines inside you loop until the `imgName` doesn't come undefined

Comment: @gfpacheco yep started doing that already as you typed your comment. Its looks like a problem when `fs` tries to open the file for the `sizeOf` class. I'll add the error in the question.

Comment: Are you sure there's no `undefined` inside your array? Be careful that `console.log` will log an empty string if you pass `undefined`

Comment: @gfpacheco done. You'll notice in the error that the file string still says `undefined`, even though I know that file (and the path I gave it) exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86663/discussion-between-gfpacheco-and-crockpotveggies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as errors unseting variables or misterious function calls messing up with them, unless they actually do change their value.

The only problem here is **there is an undefined value inside your array**.